# LINQ: Field could be int or bool - how can I use it without InvalidCastException?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I'm using a LINQ query on a DataTable where a data field may be a `bool` (true/false) or an `int` (1/0). The LINQ query asks for a type for the `Field` method and if the data field differs, an `InvalidCastException` is thrown (which cannot be caught).

```
   var query =
   from tbl12 in t12.AsEnumerable()
   where tbl12.Field<int>("theField") == 0
   select new { T12 = tbl12 };
```

or

```
   var query =
   from tbl12 in t12.AsEnumerable()
   where tbl12.Field<bool>("theField") == false
   select new { T12 = tbl12 };
```

How can I get around this? I want to filter results where the field = false or 0.

Comment: What is the *actual* backing type in the table?

Comment: @Anthony Pegram it could be either boolean or integer. It depends on the version of the program we interface with.

Comment: @sneakthief The application runs at the customers computer. The 3rd party software that's on their machine may return a bool or int depending on what version it is. Our software has to be able to read both.

Comment: Note: in MySql at least BOOL/BOOLEAN is a synonym for TINYINT(1) (1-bit integer), other sql dbrms operate alike iirc, hence the problem

Comment: I've no idea where the value comes from - it's not a database but from a method in a 3rd party DLL. I'll probably delete this question due to the poor rep I'm receiving which is a shame as it could be useful to someone else.

Comment: Maybe you should instead reformat the question, take out the int/bool stuff and make it more of a general question on casting. Or search for C# casting related questions :)

Comment: Can't you check for the version and execute a different query accordingly?

Comment: Why do you say InvalidCastException can't be caught? It's not a perfect idea, but you certainly could wrap your query in a try/catch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer: set the type as `object` and use the ToString() method on the field.

ie:

```
   var query =
   from tbl12 in t12.AsEnumerable()
   where tbl12.Field<object>("theField").ToString() == "false" || tbl12.Field<object>("theField").ToString() == "0"
   select new { T12 = tbl12 };
```

Comment: To the person who -1'd this, why?

Comment: I didn't -1 it, but I would guess it's just because it's a bad practice and inefficient. It requires your actual value to be boxed as an object, then takes the ToString() call of it and relies on it returning exactly what you're looking for. It also requires you to call the Field method twice.

Answer (score 0):

I can not think of a really clean version for this problem, so probably the best way to do this (and related things) is to use the `Convert` class like so:

```
var query =
from tbl12 in t12.AsEnumerable()
where !Convert.ToBoolean(tbl12.Field<object>("theField"))
select new { T12 = tbl12 };
```

It's not pretty, but at least this variant doesn't rely on string conversion to get the result.